# Elixir - how to deep merge maps?

Tags: elixir

With `Map.merge` I have:

```
Map.merge(%{ a: %{ b: 1 }}, %{ a: %{ c: 3 }}) # => %{ a: %{ c: 3 }}
```

but actually I want to:

```
Map.merge(%{ a: %{ b: 1 }}, %{ a: %{ c: 3 }}) # => %{ a: %{ b: 1, c: 3 }}
```

Is there any native method without writing a recursive boilerplate function for this case?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As @Dogbert suggested, you can write a function to recursively merge maps.

```
defmodule MapUtils do
  def deep_merge(left, right) do
    Map.merge(left, right, &deep_resolve/3)
  end

  # Key exists in both maps, and both values are maps as well.
  # These can be merged recursively.
  defp deep_resolve(_key, left = %{}, right = %{}) do
    deep_merge(left, right)
  end

  # Key exists in both maps, but at least one of the values is
  # NOT a map. We fall back to standard merge behavior, preferring
  # the value on the right.
  defp deep_resolve(_key, _left, right) do
    right
  end
end
```

Here are some test cases to give you an idea how conflicts are resolved:

```
ExUnit.start

defmodule MapUtils.Test do
  use ExUnit.Case

  test 'one level of maps without conflict' do
    result = MapUtils.deep_merge(%{a: 1}, %{b: 2})
    assert result == %{a: 1, b: 2}
  end

  test 'two levels of maps without conflict' do
    result = MapUtils.deep_merge(%{a: %{b: 1}}, %{a: %{c: 3}})
    assert result == %{a: %{b: 1, c: 3}}
  end

  test 'three levels of maps without conflict' do
    result = MapUtils.deep_merge(%{a: %{b: %{c: 1}}}, %{a: %{b: %{d: 2}}})
    assert result == %{a: %{b: %{c: 1, d: 2}}}
  end

  test 'non-map value in left' do
    result = MapUtils.deep_merge(%{a: 1}, %{a: %{b: 2}})
    assert result == %{a: %{b:  2}}
  end

  test 'non-map value in right' do
    result = MapUtils.deep_merge(%{a: %{b: 1}}, %{a: 2})
    assert result == %{a: 2}
  end

  test 'non-map value in both' do
    result = MapUtils.deep_merge(%{a: 1}, %{a: 2})
    assert result == %{a: 2}
  end
end
```

Comment: As small thing to be aware of here is that this will silently merge structs/custom defined types as well as on the inside they are just maps. To avoid it you can pattern match on the `__struct__` key that is present when it is a struct. To avoid people falling in these pitfalls I also wrote a [deep_merge](https://github.com/PragTob/deep_merge) library.

Answer (score 13):

If you only have 1 level nesting of maps inside maps, and all the values of the top level map are maps, you can use `Map.merge/3`:

```
iex(1)> a = %{ a: %{ b: 1 }}
%{a: %{b: 1}}
iex(2)> b = %{ a: %{ c: 3 }}
%{a: %{c: 3}}
iex(3)> Map.merge(a, b, fn _, a, b -> Map.merge(a, b) end)
%{a: %{b: 1, c: 3}}
```

For infinite nesting, I believe writing a function is the only way but in that function you can use `Map.merge/3` to reduce some code.

Answer (score 4):

As just mentioned in a comment the naive approach to deep_merge also accidentally merges all structs/custom types as they are maps internally. I made the same mistake and so implemented a [deep_merge](https://github.com/PragTob/deep_merge) library to prevent these mistakes and provide further features.

```
DeepMerge.deep_merge original_map, other_map

iex> DeepMerge.deep_merge(%{a: 1, b: %{x: 10, y: 9}}, %{b: %{y: 20, z: 30}, c: 4})
%{a: 1, b: %{x: 10, y: 20, z: 30}, c: 4}

iex> DeepMerge.deep_merge([a: 1, b: [x: 10, y: 9]], [b: [y: 20, z: 30], c: 4])
[a: 1, b: [x: 10, y: 20, z: 30], c: 4]
```

It has a couple of extra features you might (or might not) need:

- It handles both maps and keyword lists
- It does not merge structs or maps with structs…
- …but you can implement the simple DeepMerge.Resolver protocol for types/structs of your choice to also make them deep mergable
- a deep_merge/3 variant that gets a function similar to Map.merge/3 to modify the merging behavior, for instance in case you don't want keyword lists to be merged or you want all lists to be appended

Answer (score 1):

There is similar code in the source of `Mix.Config`: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/mix/lib/mix/config.ex#L302

```
@doc """
Merges two configurations.

The configuration of each application is merged together
with the values in the second one having higher preference
than the first in case of conflicts.

## Examples

    iex> Mix.Config.merge([app: [k: :v1]], [app: [k: :v2]])
    [app: [k: :v2]]

    iex> Mix.Config.merge([app1: []], [app2: []])
    [app1: [], app2: []]

"""
def merge(config1, config2) do
  Keyword.merge(config1, config2, fn _, app1, app2 ->
    Keyword.merge(app1, app2, &deep_merge/3)
  end)
end

defp deep_merge(_key, value1, value2) do
  if Keyword.keyword?(value1) and Keyword.keyword?(value2) do
    Keyword.merge(value1, value2, &deep_merge/3)
  else
    value2
  end
end
```